# Dropbox api for android returning null for AccessTokenSecret

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dropbox-api

I am using following code to authenticate with dropbox

```
AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(Constants.DROPBOX_APPKEY, Constants.DROPBOX_APPSECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(this);
```

Once done

i call

```
 mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

Account dropboxAccount =  mDBApi.accountInfo();
            String name = dropboxAccount.displayName;
            AccessTokenPair pair = mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair();
            String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
            String accessTokenSecret = pair.secret;
```

However AccessTokenPair is null. How else am i suppose to get `accessTokenSecret`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Dropbox Android Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android), the `getAccessTokenPair` method returns an OAuth 1 access token, if you have one, as an `AccessTokenPair`. The `getOAuth2AccessToken` returns an OAuth 2 access token, if you have one. Note that OAuth 2 access tokens are only one piece (i.e, basically just one string) while OAuth 1 access tokens have two pieces (key and secret).

Since you are using `startOAuth2Authentication`, you only have an OAuth 2 access token, and `getAccessTokenPair` won't return anything.

Comment: how do i get oauth1 then?

Comment: OAuth 2 is recommended over OAuth 1, but if you do still need to use OAuth 1 for some reason, you can start an OAuth 1 app authorization flow using the `startAuthentication` method: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/android/AndroidAuthSession.html#startAuthentication(android.content.Context)